# How to unify column names to append dataframes using pandas?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I have two dataframes like as shown below

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'person_id': [101,101,101,101,202,202,202],
                   'person_type':['A','A','B','C','D','B','A'],
                   'test_id':[1,2,3,3,4,4,5],
                   'login_date':['5/7/2013 09:27:00 AM','09/08/2013 11:21:00 AM','06/06/2014 08:00:00 AM','06/06/2014 05:00:00 AM','12/11/2011 10:00:00 AM','13/10/2012 12:00:00 AM','13/12/2012 11:45:00 AM']})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'subject_id': [101,101,101,101,202,202,202],
                   'test_date':['5/7/2013 09:27:00 AM','09/08/2013 11:21:00 AM','06/06/2014 08:00:00 AM','06/06/2014 05:00:00 AM','12/11/2011 10:00:00 AM','13/10/2012 12:00:00 AM','13/12/2012 11:45:00 AM']})
```

I would like to change the shape of `df2` to look like `df1`. By shape, I mean only column names.

For ex: I would like to make `df2` look exactly like `df1` in terms of column names but retain the value of df2 as it is.

I tried the below

```
df2.rename(columns={'subject_id':'person_id', 'test_date':'login_date'}, inplace=True)
final_columns = df1.columns
previous_columns = df2.columns.tolist()
mapping = {previous_columns[i]: final_columns[i] for i in range(2)}
df2.rename(mapping, inplace=True)
final_df = df1.append(df2)
```

I expect my output to be like as shown below

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly assign columns in both df's

```
df1['DATA FROM']='df1'
df2['DATA FROM']='df2'
```

Finally:

via `append()`+`rename()`:

```
df1.append(df2.rename(columns={'subject_id':'person_id','test_date':'login_date'}))
```

OR

via `concat()`+`rename()`:

```
pd.concat([df1,df2.rename(columns={'subject_id':'person_id','test_date':'login_date'})])
```

output:

```
  person_id person_type  test_id              login_date   DATA FROM
0        101           A      1.0    5/7/2013 09:27:00 AM       df1
1        101           A      2.0  09/08/2013 11:21:00 AM       df1
2        101           B      3.0  06/06/2014 08:00:00 AM       df1
3        101           C      3.0  06/06/2014 05:00:00 AM       df1
4        202           D      4.0  12/11/2011 10:00:00 AM       df1
5        202           B      4.0  13/10/2012 12:00:00 AM       df1
6        202           A      5.0  13/12/2012 11:45:00 AM       df1
0        101         NaN      NaN    5/7/2013 09:27:00 AM       df2
1        101         NaN      NaN  09/08/2013 11:21:00 AM       df2
2        101         NaN      NaN  06/06/2014 08:00:00 AM       df2
3        101         NaN      NaN  06/06/2014 05:00:00 AM       df2
4        202         NaN      NaN  12/11/2011 10:00:00 AM       df2
5        202         NaN      NaN  13/10/2012 12:00:00 AM       df2
6        202         NaN      NaN  13/12/2012 11:45:00 AM       df2
```

Comment: one quick question. I followed above solution. but after when I try to do this map operatrion `df_final["person_id"] = df_final['person_id'].map(person_identifier)`, I get the below error `ValueError: cannot reindex from a duplicate axis`

Comment: This didn't happen before append operation. Moreover, I verified that there is no duplicates in `person_identifier`. But yes, `df_final['person_id']` has duplicates (but tat shouldn't matter and is expecred). do you know what could be the issue

Comment: @TheGreat due to duplicate values in `person_identifier` you are getting this error

Comment: @TheGreat Then try merge instead of mapping or try `df_final['person_id'].map(person_identifier.drop_duplicates())` if again you are getting the same error then you have to merge instead of mapping values...merge will also give you the same result that you get from mapping(except you will get little more rowsdue to duplicated key but you can drop that as well)

Answer (score 2):

try using [`pd.concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html#pandas-concat)

```
import pandas as pd

pd.concat([
    df1.assign(Data_From="df1"),
    df2.assign(Data_From="df2") \
        .rename(columns={"subject_id": "person_id", "test_date": "login_date"})
])
```

---

```
   person_id person_type  test_id              login_date Data_From
0        101           A      1.0    5/7/2013 09:27:00 AM       df1
1        101           A      2.0  09/08/2013 11:21:00 AM       df1
2        101           B      3.0  06/06/2014 08:00:00 AM       df1
3        101           C      3.0  06/06/2014 05:00:00 AM       df1
4        202           D      4.0  12/11/2011 10:00:00 AM       df1
5        202           B      4.0  13/10/2012 12:00:00 AM       df1
6        202           A      5.0  13/12/2012 11:45:00 AM       df1
0        101         NaN      NaN    5/7/2013 09:27:00 AM       df2
1        101         NaN      NaN  09/08/2013 11:21:00 AM       df2
2        101         NaN      NaN  06/06/2014 08:00:00 AM       df2
3        101         NaN      NaN  06/06/2014 05:00:00 AM       df2
4        202         NaN      NaN  12/11/2011 10:00:00 AM       df2
5        202         NaN      NaN  13/10/2012 12:00:00 AM       df2
6        202         NaN      NaN  13/12/2012 11:45:00 AM       df2
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `concat` with the `keys` argument.

```
df3 = pd.concat([df1,df2.rename(columns=
                      {'subject_id' : 'person_id',
                      'test_date' : 'login_date'})],
             join='outer',
             keys=['df1','df2'])
```

then use `.loc` to slice your df.

```
print(df3.loc['df1'])

   person_id person_type  test_id              login_date
0        101           A      1.0    5/7/2013 09:27:00 AM
1        101           A      2.0  09/08/2013 11:21:00 AM
2        101           B      3.0  06/06/2014 08:00:00 AM
3        101           C      3.0  06/06/2014 05:00:00 AM
4        202           D      4.0  12/11/2011 10:00:00 AM
5        202           B      4.0  13/10/2012 12:00:00 AM
6        202           A      5.0  13/12/2012 11:45:00 AM
```

---

print(df3)

```
       person_id person_type  test_id              login_date
df1 0        101           A      1.0    5/7/2013 09:27:00 AM
    1        101           A      2.0  09/08/2013 11:21:00 AM
    2        101           B      3.0  06/06/2014 08:00:00 AM
    3        101           C      3.0  06/06/2014 05:00:00 AM
    4        202           D      4.0  12/11/2011 10:00:00 AM
    5        202           B      4.0  13/10/2012 12:00:00 AM
    6        202           A      5.0  13/12/2012 11:45:00 AM
df2 0        101         NaN      NaN    5/7/2013 09:27:00 AM
    1        101         NaN      NaN  09/08/2013 11:21:00 AM
    2        101         NaN      NaN  06/06/2014 08:00:00 AM
    3        101         NaN      NaN  06/06/2014 05:00:00 AM
    4        202         NaN      NaN  12/11/2011 10:00:00 AM
    5        202         NaN      NaN  13/10/2012 12:00:00 AM
    6        202         NaN      NaN  13/12/2012 11:45:00 AM
```